# Configure style used for footnotes in MS Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word

I have created a style that I want to use each time I insert a footnote. How to tell MS Word 2013 to do that automatically for me instead of manually applying them myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do so by clicking on the small arrow that appears under the Styles tab, and a list will appear with all styles to edit.

[image: A screenshot of styles list.]

Note: if you can't see the "Footnote Text", then click the "Options..." link and select "All Styles" from the dropdown.